# Gulp 4, Tasks don't execute before calling watch

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using Gulp 4 to compile my code from TypeScript to JavaScript and to build and serve the app.

I've come across one problem that I cannot solve.

I'd like to run the build, copy-html and copy-css tasks before some file gets changed.

According to Gulp documentation I just need to provide a config object with ignoreInitial set to false, but it doesn't work.

I've tried to call the three tasks before I initialize browserSync but for it also didn't work for me.

```js
gulp.task("serve", function() {
  // TODO Make a build before first serve
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./dist/"
    }
  });
  gulp
    .watch(["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html", "src/**/*.css"], {
      ignoreInitial: false
    })
    .on(
      "change",
      gulp.series(
        gulp.parallel("copy-html", "copy-css"),
        build,
        browserSync.reload
      )
    );
});
```

Comment: What is this thing you call "gulp" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using calling `.on()` on the returned [`chokidar`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) interface, add your tasks to the watch command.

```
gulp
  .watch(
    ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html", "src/**/*.css"], 
    { ignoreInitial: false }, 
    gulp.series(
      gulp.parallel("copy-html", "copy-css"),
        build,
        browserSync.reload
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Your answer guided me to correct solution. This code is correct, but there was additional problem with browserSync.reload, it wasn't notifying gulp that the reload ended. The solution to that was to wrap browserSync.reload into a function and use gulp callback that was inserted as an argument to this function.

Comment: @Terminat interesting. I've worked with BrowserSync in my Gulp scripts before, but never listened for an end of reload activity